# Multiple Aggregate Instances in one Transaction

Tags: java, c#, transactions, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I am having a problem with multiple aggregates in one transaction.

I am have a lot of nodes structured in a tree.
Node can reference his parent node by id. Node has alot of write methods.

```
public class Node {
    private NodeID nodeID;

    public void changeNodeData(NodeData nodeData);
    public void changeParent(Node node);
    public void changeType(Type type);
    //... next write methods
}
```

We can build `tree structure` from nodes.
But there is concept of `working tree structure`.
To `working tree structure`, you can `add operations`, which are just operations you can do at nodes. For example `ChangeParentOperation`

```
public class WorkingTreeStructure {
    private Array<Operation> operations;

    public void add(Operation operation);
}
```

There can be only one `working tree structure` at the same time and it can exists as long as the user wants, till we `apply it`.
`Applying it to the tree structure`, basically means for each operation `find node` and `call node's method`, with necessary arguments.
Such `working tree structure` can modify a lot of nodes. And we need to do it: `apply all operations` or `none` (if there is an error).

According to Vaughn Vernon's principles, we can create a lot of nodes in one transaction. But we need to modify/delete a lot of nodes in the same transaction also here.
So what should I do in such situation?

Comment: We're missing the whole domain and transaction analysis you did (or didn't do) here. How collaborative is your domain ? Why choose `Node` as an Aggregate Root ? How much concurrent access is there to a `Node` ? What invariants does it enforce ? Does it ever happen that a `Node` is modified alone, not as part of a Tree Structure modification ? so on and so forth.

Comment: I found way to do it. I created TreeStructure aggregate root, which hold direct reference to nodes. Every nodes can have direct reference to child nodes. 
At every request I don't recreate the whole aggregate from db, because It can hold up to 3000 nodes, so I keep the fresh TreeStructure in cache. 
Thanks to that I have one aggregate, which can be modified freely and answering to your question concurrency is not a problem here. :)

Answer (score 0):

An operation here is an example of the command pattern if i understand things correctly. So it looks something like this

```
class Operation {

   public void Execlute() {
       /* modify node here */
   }
}
```

If you implement your operation like this that also means you can speicfy an undo operation. For example like this

```
class DeleteNode : Operation {

     public override void Execute() {
         /* delete node here */
     }

     public override void Undo() {
         /* reinsert node here */
     }
}
```

Now you could implement your transaction like this

```
 public void ExecuteTransaction(Array<Operation> operations) {

     bool exception = false;
     int index = 0;

     try {
        for(; index < operations.length; ++index) {
           operations[i].execute();
        }
     }
     catch (exception ex) {
         exception = true;
     }

     if (exception) {
        for(;index >= 0; --index) {
            operations[index].undo();
        }
     }
 }
```

**Advanced reading:**
Depending on which language/toolset/framework you are using exactly some of them might have support for undoable transactions and you might rely on that.

One i like personally is postsharp http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/New-in-PostSharp-32-UndoRedo

Another often easier way is to just persist your data and load a previous version if you want to do a rollback

Answer (score 0):

The aggregate should be the tree itself rather than the nodes of those trees.  Thus, when you change a collection of nodes within a tree, the transaction only covers one aggregate root (the tree) rather than the a collection of aggregate roots (the individual nodes).

You are on the right track.  The WorkingTreeStructure class simply needs a "apply" function which applies the operations to the nodes of the tree and finalizes the working tree structure.

```
public class WorkingTreeStructure {
    private Array<Operation> operations;

    public void add(Operation operation) {...}
    public void apply() {...}
}
```

This makes sense given your domain:

> There can be only one working tree structure at the same time and it
>   can exists as long as the user wants, till we **apply** it